# Complexity class of Towers of Hanoi

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

Given a problem

> Given n print every step it takes to move n disks from rode 1 to rode
>   2

I need to determine the complexity class of this problem with this specific task. It is clearly not in `P` as it is obvious that complexity of this problem is `O(2^n)` and we can't do better as we have to print output of exponential size. My next guess would be NP or even NP-hard but I think it can't be the case as not matter how clever the algorithm is, we can't check the exponential size output in polynomial time even on non-determinant machine. So, what's the complexity class?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. The program is already written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct steps can be determined from the start without needing a trial-error search to make the right decision. Therefore this problem is not a [decision problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_problem), to which classes such as [NP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_(complexity)) apply.

This is more of a [function problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_problem). The time complexity is indeed determined by the number of steps to be output, which is 2<sup>n</sup>-1, i.e. *O(2<sup>n</sup>)*.

The corresponding class would thus be **FEXPTIME-Complete**, the prefixed *F* standing for *Function*, and *Complete* signifying that it cannot be done in less than exponential time (like *P*). It is analogous to the [EXPTIME-Complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXPTIME) class for decision problems, i.e. *O(2<sup>polynomial(n)</sup>)*.

#### Decision problem

There is a confusing aspect in your question: The problem statement is about printing steps, reaffirmed by *"... determine the complexity class of this problem"*. Yet some phrases down the line, you mention *"we can't check the exponential size output in polynomial time"*. So it seems you mix two different problems:

1. Generating the (correct) list of steps for a given n
2. Verifying the correctness given n and a list of steps.

The second *is* a decision problem, and in that case you would say it is in the EXPTIME-Complete class.